# How can I visualize the diffrent time intervals by choosing the diffrent modes of transport in my Shiny bar plot?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I make my Barchart interactive? I want to see the arrival time by choosing the different modes of transport. I am able to run the app, however, it is impossible to make it interactive.

The variable `Arrival` are time intervals.
The variable `Mode` are modes of transport.
The variable `Answer` means Yes/No.

This is a part of my dataframe:

```
> head(Data_Long)
    Id               Arrival    Mode Answer
1   54 6:00 p.m. - 6:30 p.m. On foot    Yes
2  132 5:30 p.m. - 6:00 p.m. On foot    Yes
3  600 5:00 p.m. - 5:30 p.m. On foot    Yes
4  620 4:00 p.m. - 5:00 p.m. On foot    Yes
5  951 5:30 p.m. - 6:00 p.m. On foot    Yes
6 1011 4:00 p.m. - 5:00 p.m. On foot    Yes
```

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

#Read in Excel
Survey <- read_excel("04_Participant.xlsx")

Data <- subset(Survey, select = c(1, 4:14))

colnames(Data) <- c(
  'Id',
  'Arrival',
  'On foot',
  'Bicycle',
  'Bicycle (Yélo)',
  'Motorcycle/scooter',
  'Scooter (trotinette)',
  'Bus',
  'Train',
  'Car',
  'Carpool',
  'Car (Yélo)'
)


Data_Long <- Data %>% 
  gather(key="Mode",
         value = "Answer",
         c(-Id, -`Arrival`))

Data_Long <- subset(Data_Long, Answer=="Yes")

Data_Long <- as.data.frame(Data_Long)

Data_Long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Arrival))+
  geom_histogram(stat="count")


# ui.R ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Arrival times"),  # Add a title panel
  sidebarLayout(  
    position = "right",
                  
    sidebarPanel(h3("Inputs for histogram"),
                 selectInput("Mode", "Select mode", choices = c("On foot"="On foot",
                                                                "Bicycle" = "Bicycle",
                                                                "Bicycle (Yélo)"="Bicycle (Yélo)",
                                                                "Motorcycle/scooter"="Motorcycle/scooter",
                                                                "Scooter (trotinette)"="Scooter (trotinette)",
                                                                "Bus"="Bus",
                                                                "Train" = "Train",
                                                                "Car" = "Car",
                                                                "Carpool"="Carpool",
                                                                "Car (Yélo)"= "Car (Yélo)"),
                                                                  selected = "Car"),
                 br(),
                 
                 
                 ),
    
    # Inside the sidebarLayout, add a sidebarPanel
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myhist")
      #tableOutput("mytable"),
      #textOutput("mytext")
      
    )  
  )
)

# server.R ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$myhist <- renderPlot(
  
    Data_Long %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Arrival))
    + geom_histogram(stat="count",group=input$Mode, data = Data_Long[Data_Long$Mode==input$Mode])
    

  )
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected
  [No stack trace available]
```

This is a picture of the shiny app when I run it:
[image: Shiny app]

Comment: And I have edited my answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
output$myhist <- renderPlot(
    Data_Long %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Arrival)) +
    geom_histogram(stat="count",group=input$Mode, data = Data_Long[Data_Long$Mode==input$Mode, ])
    
    
  )
```

1. In `ggplot` chain `+` sign has to be used on the end of each line (element of chain), not on the beginning.
2. I just learned that when you subset `data.frame` object using `[` and do not include comma and there is no observation you are looking for in the data frame, then you will get 0 columns and 2 rows:

```
> Data_Long[Data_Long$Mode == "Car"]
data frame with 0 columns and 2 rows
```

But when you use comma, then you will get 0 rows, but all columns:

```
> Data_Long[Data_Long$Mode == "Car", ]
[1] id      Arrival Mode    Answer 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

And this is a reason why you are getting `Error: undefined columns selected` - there is no such column as `Arrival` if you subset without comma **and** searching for an observation which do not exists ('Car' does not exist in your data.frame used as an example - you can choose in your app 'On foot' and you should see a plot instead of error). Or you can use comma as I did above.

Comment: Hello gss. I tried this in the plot, but it did not work. I will try to rewrite my question. Thank you.